# How can I page output spark-shell

Tags: scala, apache-spark

How do I page output written to the spark-shell console?  For example, when I run the following command to list the defined terms from my session I often get a long list of output that exceeds the number of rows in my terminal.

`$intp.definedTerms.foreach{println(_)}`

In a `bash` shell I would use `less` to page output from a command or program.  Is there paging functionality, similar to `less`, available to spark-shell?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

spark-shell doesn't but at the end I link to info about Spark's pipe() action on RDDs that let's you fork output to external programs.

WINDOW SCROLLING?

You don't say which environment you are in?

If for example you are in Unity in Ubuntu, or almost any windowing system, would the scrolling function of a terminal window satisfy your needs?

You can edit .bashrc and modify that scrolling setting before calling spark-shell.

There are also some useful GUI-based ways to affect window scrolling: https://askubuntu.com/questions/385901/how-to-see-more-lines-in-the-terminal

Here's another page with more suggestions on editing .bashrc, again more info on your environment would be helpful. https://askubuntu.com/questions/51122/setting-gnome-terminal-window-size-from-within-bashrc

PIPE ACTIONS on RDDS in Spark

Further, without your specific code it's hard to know if this is applicable, there's a way to pipe the output of actions on RDDs to external programs. See http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#transformations, here's an excerpt:

> Pipe each partition of the RDD through a shell command, e.g. a Perl
>   or bash script. RDD elements are written to the process's stdin and
>   lines output to its stdout are returned as an RDD of strings.

Comment: Thanks for pushing me on scrolling.  I use GNU screen which disables the scroll bars in my terminal window.  It turns out you can enter "copy mode" [C-a ESC] which allows you to move up and down the screen using Page Up and Page Down or the arrow keys.

Comment: Ha-ha that's awesome, sounds like emacs :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ammonite-spark](https://github.com/alexarchambault/ammonite-spark) to use Ammonite instead of spark-shell, and it has [`browse`](https://ammonite.io/#browse) function to page any value.