# Equivalent to "less" or "more" command in Scala Spark

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

Is there a way to make the scala display a lengthy output in the form of pages, much like we do in bash prompt by using `less` or `more`.

```
scala> df.show(10000)
```

displays all the lines at once, and I need to scroll up till the top to read the top content.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34796683/how-can-i-page-output-spark-shell

Comment: use a notebook, like zeppelin,spark-notebook or databricks; those environments allow for a sortable, paginated view on the dataframe. Alternatively, use another software to view your tables like SQL Developer etc